# How to hide roaming network icon from Status bar?

Tags: notification-icons, roaming

I'm using Lava Iris Atom 2 phone with Vodafone's SIM. I'm in home network. Problem is, I see the roaming icon in the Status bar.

I tried all the settings like select network or hide roam.  If I remove click from data roam, my internet wont work.

Please give  an accurate answer  on how to remove roam network icon from Status bar?

Answer (score 1):

You Android needs to be rooted because that icon is managed by SystemUI and you can't tweak it without having root privileges.

A simple way is to use GravityBox (requires [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)). It is available for [Jelly Bean](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox), [Kitkat](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox) and [Lollipop](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.lollipop.gravitybox).

1. Install it → activate its module → launch it
2. Go to **Statusbar tweaks** → check **Disable roaming indicators**

That's it.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: Unfortunately, the "disable roaming indicators" setting seems to be no longer available (tried on Marshmallow)

Comment: I see. See if this module helps. http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.caze.roamingcontrol